# Weird ifstream behaviour

Tags: c++, algorithm

Writing code to write object into a file, read them, and print on the screen

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class employee{
    private:
        string name;
        unsigned long ID;
    public:
        employee():name(""),ID(0){}
        void putdata(){cout<<"Enter employee's name: ";cin>>name;cout<<"Enter employee's ID: ";cin>>ID;}
        void getdata(){cout<<"Employee's name is: "<<name<<endl;cout<<"Employee's ID is: "<<ID<<endl;}
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream&,employee&);
        friend istream& operator >> (istream&,employee&);
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& f,employee& emp){ // запись объекта в файл
    f<<emp.ID<<"-"<<emp.name<<"?";
    return f;
}

istream& operator >> (istream& f,employee& empl){ // чтение объекта из файла
    char dummy;
    f>>empl.ID>>dummy;
    f>>dummy;
    empl.name="";
    while(dummy!='?'){
        empl.name+=dummy;
        f>>dummy;       
    }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(){
    char ch='y';
    ofstream file1;
    ifstream file2;
    file1.open("TAB.txt");
    employee one;
    while(ch=='y'){ // цикл для записи
        one.putdata();
        file1<<one; // write data into file
        cout<<"Go on?(y,n): ";cin>>ch;
    }
    file1.close();
    file2.open("TAB.txt");
    while(file2.good()){ // цикл для чтения из файла
        file2>>one;
        one.getdata();      
    }
    file2.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

After entering objects, th program print them out and hanging. I guess there is a problem with while(file2.good()) but I'm not sure. Can anyone comment?

Comment: It means `file2` is not `good` - does the file exist? Also try `cout << strerror(errno)`.

Comment: `file1.open()`     creates a file

Comment: You might want to have `cout<<"Go on?(y,n): " << std::endl;` as some implementations won't allow input while there is an incomplete line of output  on a terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you have missed is that `EOF` is not set until you read **past** the end of file. The last successful read will read up-to (but not past) the end of file and thus `EOF` is `false` and `good()` is `true` but there will be no more data on the stream (so the next read will fail).

This is why you need to check that a read from a stream succeeds. To aid in this when you use a stream object in a boolean context (while/if test) it converts itself to boolean the value being the state of the stream.

```
 if (stream) {
      std::cout << "stream is in good state\n";
 }
```

Also the input `operator>>` returns a stream (so it can be chained) so the result of a read can also be used in a test.

```
 if (stream >> value) {
      std::cout << "The read worked.\n";
 }
```

Your problem is you are not correctly checking the state of the input stream after reading.

```
istream& operator >> (istream& f,employee& empl)
{
    char dummy;
    f>>empl.ID>>dummy;  // Did this work?
                        // You did not test the state of `f` after the read.
    f>>dummy;
    empl.name="";
    while(dummy!='?'){
        empl.name+=dummy;
        f>>dummy;          // Again if this read fails
                           // because you reached the end of file
                           // then the variable 'dummy' is not updated
                           // then this will go into an infinite loop.
    }
}
```

Every read should check the state of the stream.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& f, employee& empl)
{
    // The other standard thing is that if the read fails.
    // then you should not alter the state of your object.
    // so read into a temporary object.
    char dummy;


    employee tmp;
    if (f >> tmp.id >> dummy && dummy == '-')
    {
        // We have correctly read the ID (and following '-' char)
        // Note: The output operator outputs '-' after the ID.
        // Now we try and read the name.

        // While the read of the character worked.
        // and the character is not '?' keep adding it to
        // name. If we reach then end of the file this
        // loop will exit.
        while(f >> dummy && dummy != '?')
        {
           tmp.name += dummy;
        }

        // If the stream is still good.
        // then update the object.
        // If the stream is not good then something went wrong
        // we reached the end of file before we found the '?'
        if (f)
        {
            using std::swap;
            swap(tmp, empl);
        }
    }
    return f;
}
```

Now that the input operator is good. We can correctly write the output loop.

```
while(file2.good()){
    file2>>one;
    one.getdata();      
}
```

The problem with this is that `file2>>one` may fail. You should test for that.

```
while(file2.good()){
    if (file2 >> one) {
        one.getdata();     
    } 
}
```

But to do this correctly put the read as the condition of the while. Then you don't even enter the loop if the read fails.

```
while(file2 >> one)
{
    one.getdata();      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It finally works(I can't belive):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class employee{
    private:
        string name;
        unsigned long ID;
    public:
        employee():name(""),ID(0){}
        void putdata(){cout<<"Enter employee's name: ";cin>>name;cout<<"Enter employee's ID: ";cin>>ID;}
        void getdata(){cout<<"Employee's name is: "<<name<<endl;cout<<"Employee's ID is: "<<ID<<endl;}
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream&,employee&);
        friend istream& operator >> (istream&,employee&);
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& f,employee& emp){ // запись объекта в файл
    f<<emp.ID<<"-"<<emp.name<<"?";
    return f;
}

istream& operator >> (istream& f,employee& empl){ // чтение объекта из файла
    char dummy;
    f>>empl.ID>>dummy;
    f>>dummy;
    empl.name="";
    while(dummy!='?'){
        empl.name+=dummy;
        f>>dummy;       
    }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(){
    char ch='y';
    ofstream file1;
    ifstream file2;
    file1.open("TAB.txt");
    employee one;
    while(ch=='y'){ // цикл для записи
        one.putdata();
        file1<<one; // write data into file
        cout<<"Go on?(y,n): ";cin>>ch;
    }
    file1.close();
    file2.open("TAB.txt");
    while(file2.good()&&file2.peek()!=EOF){ // цикл для чтения из файла

        file2>>one;
        one.getdata();      
    }
    file2.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I've added `file2.peek()!=EOF` condition